# Separate multiple SQL statments in one query in the RESULTS of the run query

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have the query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Network_Devices
WHERE Function Like '*irewall*'
GROUP BY Site;
Union
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Network_Devices
WHERE Decom = "No"
GROUP BY Site;
union
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Physical_Devices
WHERE Decom = "No"
GROUP BY Site;
union
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Rack_Site AS Other
FROM Racks
GROUP BY Rack_Site;
union
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Cluster AS Other
FROM Virtual_Devices
WHERE Decomissioned = "No"
GROUP BY Cluster;
union
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, OS AS Other
FROM Virtual_Devices
WHERE Decomissioned = "No"
GROUP BY OS;
union
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Location AS Other
FROM Virtual_Devices
WHERE Decomissioned = "No"
GROUP BY Location;
```

There are multiple select statements inside and when the query is run, the rows are in a random order and not grouped in their respective statements. Is there any way to separate or group the rows when the results are viewed or exported to excel?

Comment: Not really related to the question, but your use of `DISTINCT` is completely redundant, firstly by your group by that ensures unique groups, secondly by the use of `UNION` which only returns distinct results.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT 1 as GroupId, (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Network_Devices
WHERE Function Like '*irewall*'
GROUP BY Site;
Union
SELECT DISTINCT 2,  (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Network_Devices
WHERE Decom = "No"
GROUP BY Site;
union
SELECT DISTINCT 3, (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Physical_Devices
WHERE Decom = "No"
GROUP BY Site;
union    
SELECT DISTINCT 4, (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Rack_Site AS Other
FROM Racks
GROUP BY Rack_Site;
union
SELECT DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Cluster AS Other
FROM Virtual_Devices
WHERE Decomissioned = "No"
GROUP BY Cluster;
union
SELECT DISTINCT 5, (Count(ID)) AS Stat, OS AS Other
FROM Virtual_Devices
WHERE Decomissioned = "No"
GROUP BY OS;
union
SELECT DISTINCT 6, (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Location AS Other
FROM Virtual_Devices
WHERE Decomissioned = "No"
GROUP BY Location;
) ORDER BY GroupId
```

You can use GroupId column to sort or group, as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

Add an additional column to your statements, like this

```
SELECT 'irewall' [group], DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Network_Devices
WHERE Function Like '*irewall*'
GROUP BY Site;
Union
SELECT 'Decom=No', DISTINCT (Count(ID)) AS Stat, Site AS Other
FROM Network_Devices
WHERE Decom = "No"
GROUP BY Site;
union
...
```

so you will able to group those rows by the values of [group]